# Переадресация nginx, настройка на вложенную папку, конвертирование htaccess

Tags: nginx, php-nginx

Получилось сделать с помощью нужную мне переадресацию на пхп и статику для всех ссылок,

```
  if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 break;
   }
```

но не получается сделать для некоторых папок, что бы была с другой ссылкой на индекс и параметров, например `/folder/index.php?param=$1 break;`,

Переношу правила htaccess и пара папок было открыто для доступа, но там в query string нужен другой параметр, пример .htaccess из одной из папок

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?test=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Сам конфиг

```
server {

    root /var/www/site;
    charset utf-8;
   
    #location ~* / {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 break;
        }
    #}
    location ~* /folder/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([^?]*) /folder/index.php?test=$1 break;
        }
    }
  
    location ~* /something/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([^?]*) /something/index.php?param=$1 break;
        }
    }

    location ~* /some/config/ {
        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/([^?]*) /some/config/index.php?image=$1 break;
        }
    }
    
    location = / {
        index index.php;
    }    

    location / {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~* \.(gif|jpg|png|js|css|ttf|woff|ico)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~* /index\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;   
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите пример ссылок, как они выглядят у вас и как должны роутиться. Или можете сами посмотреть как работают ваши location например [здесь](https://nginx.viraptor.info/)